# Graphite not accepting data from collectd

Tags: graphite, collectd

I am currently having an issue with getting collectd 5.4.0 to work with graphite/carbon.

I am currently using the write_graphite plugin with collectd with the following configuration:

```
<Plugin write_graphite>
  <Carbon>
     Host "127.0.0.1"
     Port "2003"
     #Prefix "collectd."
     Protocol "udp"
     EscapeCharacter "_"
     #StoreRates true
     #AlwaysAppendDS false
        SeparateInstances true
  </Carbon>
</Plugin>
```

However, graphite indicates that my data is invalid

```
13/07/2014 23:32:52 :: invalid line received from client 127.0.0.1:43335, ignoring
```

I have done a few ngreps of the data being sent to graphite:

```
U 127.0.0.1:38327 -> 127.0.0.1:2003
  MollyQuinn.processes.ps_state.running 0.000000 1405319626..MollyQuinn.processes.ps_state.zombies 0.000000 1405319626..MollyQuinn.processes.
  ps_state.stopped 0.000000 1405319626..MollyQuinn.processes.ps_state.sleeping 70.000000 1405319626..MollyQuinn.processes.ps_state.paging 0.0
  00000 1405319626..MollyQuinn.processes.ps_state.blocked 0.000000 1405319626..MollyQuinn.processes.fork_rate 1.599984 1405319626..MollyQuinn
  .cpu.even-average.cpu.steal 0.000000 1405319636..MollyQuinn.cpu.even-average.cpu.idle 99.200106 1405319636..MollyQuinn.cpu.even-average.cpu
  .user 0.200000 1405319636..MollyQuinn.cpu.even-average.cpu.system 0.100000 1405319636..MollyQuinn.cpu.even-average.cpu.wait 0.000000 140531
  9636..MollyQuinn.cpu.even-average.cpu.nice 0.000000 1405319636..MollyQuinn.cpu.0.cpu.user 0.200001 1405319636..MollyQuinn.cpu.0.cpu.idle 99
  .400488 1405319636..MollyQuinn.cpu.0.cpu.nice 0.000000 1405319636..MollyQuinn.cpu.0.cpu.wait 0.000000 1405319636..MollyQuinn.cpu.0.cpu.inte
  rrupt 0.000000 1405319636..MollyQuinn.cpu.0.cpu.softirq 0.000000 1405319636..MollyQuinn.cpu.1.cpu.user 0.200001 1405319636..MollyQuinn.cpu.
  1.cpu.nice 0.000000 1405319636..MollyQuinn.cpu.1.cpu.system 0.100001 1405319636..MollyQuinn.cpu.1.cpu.idle 99.400510 1405319636..MollyQuinn
  .cpu.1.cpu.wait 0.000000 1405319636..MollyQuinn.cpu.1.cpu.interrupt 0.000000 1405319636..MollyQuinn.cpu.1.cpu.softirq 0.000000 1405319636..

U 127.0.0.1:34732 -> 127.0.0.1:2003
  MollyQuinn.interface.venet0.if_errors.rx 0.000000 1405319636..MollyQuinn.interface.venet0.if_errors.tx 0.000000 1405319636..MollyQuinn.cpu.
  even-average.cpu.softirq 0.000000 1405319636..MollyQuinn.interface.gre0.if_octets.rx 0.000000 1405319636..MollyQuinn.interface.gre0.if_octe
  ts.tx 0.000000 1405319636..MollyQuinn.interface.gre0.if_packets.rx 0.000000 1405319636..MollyQuinn.interface.gre0.if_packets.tx 0.000000 14
  05319636..MollyQuinn.interface.gre0.if_errors.rx 0.000000 1405319636..MollyQuinn.interface.gre0.if_errors.tx 0.000000 1405319636..MollyQuin
  n.interface.gretap0.if_octets.rx 0.000000 1405319636..MollyQuinn.interface.gretap0.if_octets.tx 0.000000 1405319636..MollyQuinn.interface.g
  retap0.if_packets.rx 0.000000 1405319636..MollyQuinn.interface.gretap0.if_packets.tx 0.000000 1405319636..MollyQuinn.interface.gretap0.if_e
  rrors.rx 0.000000 1405319636..MollyQuinn.interface.gretap0.if_errors.tx 0.000000 1405319636..MollyQuinn.interface.ip6tnl0.if_octets.rx 0.00
  0000 1405319636..MollyQuinn.interface.ip6tnl0.if_octets.tx 0.000000 1405319636..MollyQuinn.interface.ip6tnl0.if_packets.rx 0.000000 1405319
  636..MollyQuinn.interface.ip6tnl0.if_packets.tx 0.000000 1405319636..MollyQuinn.interface.ip6tnl0.if_errors.rx 0.000000 1405319636..MollyQu
  inn.interface.ip6tnl0.if_errors.tx 0.000000 1405319636..                                                                                   

U 127.0.0.1:59566 -> 127.0.0.1:2003
  MollyQuinn.processes.ps_state.paging 0.000000 1405319636..MollyQuinn.processes.ps_state.blocked 0.000000 1405319636..MollyQuinn.processes.f
  ork_rate 1.099840 1405319636..MollyQuinn.cpu.even-average.cpu.softirq 0.000000 1405319646..MollyQuinn.cpu.even-average.cpu.interrupt 0.0000
  00 1405319646..MollyQuinn.cpu.even-average.cpu.wait 0.000000 1405319646..MollyQuinn.cpu.even-average.cpu.idle 99.399707 1405319646..MollyQu
  inn.cpu.even-average.cpu.user 0.199999 1405319646..MollyQuinn.cpu.even-average.cpu.nice 0.000000 1405319646..MollyQuinn.cpu.even-average.cp
  u.system 0.100000 1405319646..MollyQuinn.cpu.even-average.cpu.steal 0.000000 1405319646..MollyQuinn.cpu.0.cpu.system 0.100000 1405319646..M
  ollyQuinn.cpu.0.cpu.user 0.100000 1405319646..MollyQuinn.cpu.0.cpu.idle 99.299534 1405319646..MollyQuinn.cpu.0.cpu.wait 0.000000 1405319646
  ..MollyQuinn.cpu.0.cpu.interrupt 0.000000 1405319646..MollyQuinn.cpu.0.cpu.softirq 0.000000 1405319646..MollyQuinn.cpu.0.cpu.steal 0.000000
   1405319646..MollyQuinn.cpu.1.cpu.user 0.099999 1405319646..MollyQuinn.cpu.1.cpu.nice 0.000000 1405319646..MollyQuinn.cpu.1.cpu.system 0.09
  9999 1405319646..MollyQuinn.cpu.0.cpu.nice 0.000000 1405319646..MollyQuinn.cpu.1.cpu.idle 99.299478 1405319646..MollyQuinn.cpu.1.cpu.softir
  q 0.000000 1405319646..MollyQuinn.cpu.1.cpu.wait 0.000000 1405319646..MollyQuinn.cpu.1.cpu.steal 0.000000 1405319646..MollyQuinn.cpu.2.cpu.
  user 0.099999 1405319646..                                                                                                                 

U 127.0.0.1:41714 -> 127.0.0.1:2003
  MollyQuinn.interface.gre0.if_errors.rx 0.000000 1405319646..MollyQuinn.interface.gre0.if_errors.tx 0.000000 1405319646..MollyQuinn.interfac
  e.gretap0.if_octets.rx 0.000000 1405319646..MollyQuinn.interface.gretap0.if_octets.tx 0.000000 1405319646..MollyQuinn.interface.gretap0.if_
  packets.rx 0.000000 1405319646..MollyQuinn.interface.gretap0.if_packets.tx 0.000000 1405319646..MollyQuinn.interface.gretap0.if_errors.rx 0
  .000000 1405319646..MollyQuinn.interface.gretap0.if_errors.tx 0.000000 1405319646..MollyQuinn.interface.ip6tnl0.if_octets.rx 0.000000 14053
  19646..MollyQuinn.interface.ip6tnl0.if_octets.tx 0.000000 1405319646..MollyQuinn.interface.ip6tnl0.if_packets.rx 0.000000 1405319646..Molly
  Quinn.interface.ip6tnl0.if_packets.tx 0.000000 1405319646..MollyQuinn.interface.ip6tnl0.if_errors.rx 0.000000 1405319646..MollyQuinn.interf
  ace.ip6tnl0.if_errors.tx 0.000000 1405319646..MollyQuinn.interface.tap0.if_octets.rx 113.498675 1405319646..MollyQuinn.interface.tap0.if_oc
  tets.tx 406.395256 1405319646..MollyQuinn.interface.tap0.if_packets.rx 0.699992 1405319646..MollyQuinn.interface.tap0.if_packets.tx 0.49999
  4 1405319646..MollyQuinn.interface.tap0.if_errors.rx 0.000000 1405319646..MollyQuinn.interface.tap0.if_errors.tx 0.000000 1405319646..Molly
  Quinn.memory.memory.used 583512064.000000 1405319646..MollyQuinn.memory.memory.buffered 0.000000 1405319646..MollyQuinn.memory.memory.cache
  d 474173440.000000 1405319646..
```